# GORM [error] unsupported data type: &[], incorrect schema

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

GORM v1.25.1, I'm tryping to run `DB.AutoMigrate()` on `Worker`, `Poster` and `Job` models but running into `[error] unsupported data type: &[]`. The Worker and Job struct should have a `many-to-many relation`, while Poster and Job should have `one-to-many` relation. Worker and experience, worker and preference both should be a `one-to-many` relation. Please help.

```
package model

type experience struct {
    gorm.Model
    Company  int    `json:"company"`
    JobTitle string `json:"jobTitle"`
    WorkerID uint
}

type preference struct {
    gorm.Model
    JobTitle string `json:"JobTitle"`
    MinPay   int    `json:"minPay"`
    MaxPay   int    `json:"maxPay"`
    WorkerID uint
}

type Worker struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username     string       `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"username"`
        ...more fields
    Experience   []experience `json:"experience"`
    Preference   []preference `json:"preference"`
    AppliedJobs  []Job        `gorm:"many2many:worker_jobs;" json:"appliedJobs"`
}

type Poster struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name       string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"name"`
    Email      string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"email"`
    Phone      string `json:"phone"`
    JobsPosted []Job  `json:"jobsPosted"`
}

type Job struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string   `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"title"`
        ...more fields
    PosterID uint `json:"posterID"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you need with the following code.

> Please note that, for the sake of the demo, I simplified your models (structs) by including only the relevant fields for the associations. If I omitted something worth mentioning, feel free to ask for it and I'll update my answer.

Let me first share the code, then I'll explain it in detail.

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Worker struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"username"`

    Posters []Poster `gorm:"many2many:workers_posters;joinForeignKey:postersId"`
}

type Poster struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"name"`
    Email string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"email"`
    Phone string `json:"phone"`

    Workers []Worker `gorm:"many2many:workers_posters;joinForeignKey:workersId"`
    Jobs    []Job
}

type Job struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title    string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null" json:"title"`
    PosterID uint   `json:"posterID"`
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Worker{}, &Poster{}, &Job{})
}
```

As your question involve both the `many2many` and the `one2many` relationship, I'm gonna divide my answer into two parts.

#### The `many2many` relationship

To achieve this relationship, you've to add the annotation `gorm:"many2many:workers_posters;joinForeignKey:workersId"` next to the slices that hold associated entities. The affected fields are:

- `Posters` field within the `Worker` struct
- `Workers` field within the `Poster` struct

Obviously, you've to change the value for the `joinForeignKey` depending on what field you're about to set.

#### The `one2many` relationship

This relationship is even simpler as you don't have to specify the join table that has to be created in a `many2many` association (e.g. the above created `workers_posters` table). Here, you only have to do these two changes:

1. Add the `Jobs []Job` field within the `Poster` struct
2. Add the `PosterID uint` field within the `Job` struct

Thanks to this, if you run the `Automigrate` method, you'll see the right tables in the database with all of the foreign keys correctly set up.

Let me know, thanks!